how to test a controller method echoing something?
I'm diving into a legacy symfony project with some controller methods echoing stuff (I know it's bad, ugly,... and I would change that eventually but for now I must not change any code, just add tests)
here's an example of such method:
    public function index(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        [...]
        echo "KO";
        exit;
    }


(please don't judge ><)
and here's a very simple test:
    public function testResponse()
    {
        $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            $this->router->generate('/')
        );
        
        $this->assertContains(
            'KO',
            $this->client->getResponse()->getContent()
        );
    }

but of course KO is echoed and test suite stops
end test
I tried some solutions with output buffer and StreamedResponse but same (and echo is not a Response at all ^^)
how could I test that route at least responds without changing anything in the controller?
NB: symfony 3.4, phpunit 6.5, php 7.4

PHPUnit has output assertions for the echo and exit is very hard to test for, you can override it with uopz https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uopz.php , but why not starting returning a response there or just returning? Another alternative is to throw an "ExitException" and handle it further up.

as I said, I cannot change controller, just add tests...
I hope we'll be able to change that kind of code in the future but for now we must not touch anything :(

for exit then there is uopz you can make use of in tests. keep it in a dedicated testsuite so that you can execute it isolated for these hard to test areas. then the test-runner won't exit while you execute the test. If those are the requirements, those are the requirements.

public function testResponse()
{
    // Mock the Request and ObjectManager
    // Create an instance of the controller

    // Start output buffering to capture echo
    ob_start();
    try {
        // Call the index method
        $controller->index($request, $manager);
        $output = ob_get_clean(); // Capture the output
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        ob_end_clean(); // Clean the output buffer if an exception is thrown
        throw $e;
    }

    $this->assertEquals('KO', $output);

}


hi! thanks for that, it sounded good but still the exit; messes up with everything :(
